# Javascript SDK on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I am trying to use the Javascript SDK for Facebook but I keep getting the message :

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains

but I have copied and pasted my canvas URL from the settings section. Anyone any ideas whats up?

my line of code is :

```
var myDomain='https://www.foxenet.com/fb/passwords/channel.html';
```

initialisation script:

```
 // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : gAppID, // App ID from the App Dashboard
      channelUrl : myDomain, // Channel File for x-domain communication
      status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
      cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
    });
```

Comment: This is probably more appropriate for SO instead of P.SE.  If you agree, please flag the question and request migration to SO.  Please do not simply cross-post this question to SO; the moderators can migrate it for you.

Comment: Please paste your initialization code (so we can see what values you put in). Chances are, either those values, or your application configuration, are borked.